# PyQt QProgressDialog not reponding

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, sleep, qprogressdialog

I am new in programming in PyQt (python interface), I like to use QProgressDialog, to show the progress of some tasks, so, the problem is, I had this:

[image]

while the change the value of progress , thank you for the help

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 160, 231, 161))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.p = QProgressDialog('titel','',0,10000)
    self.p.setValue(0)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("label test"))
def work(self):
    for index in range(10001):
       time.sleep(2)
       self.p.setValue(index)
       print(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.work()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour]

Answer (score 0):

PyQt creates a loop through `app.exec_()`, and this serves to manage the GUI dynamics such as signals, events, etc. So if you interrupt that cycle you would have problems like the one shown. And in its case `sleep()` blocks the execution of the program. One way to solve this problem is using a `QTimer` as shown below:

```
[...]
    self.p = QProgressDialog('title','',0,10000)
    self.p.setValue(0)
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(MainWindow)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.work)
    self.timer.start(2000)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
[...]
def work(self):
    self.p.setValue(self.p.value()+1)
    if self.p.value() == self.p.maximum():
        self.timer.stop()
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, after analyse your solution et after the test ,it work, but if the method work have a lot of tasks , in other word it take a lot of time , we will return to same problem, your solution is perfect for periodic tasks

Comment: If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour]